# How to create .htaccess file to rewite Wordpress URL with path in Docker?

Tags: wordpress, docker-compose

My problem is simple but I can't find a solution anywhere. I want to install a Wordpress site in a docker container in the default path `data:/var/www/html` I want to be able to access my site at `mydomain.com/blog/`. My code gives me an infinite redirect loop.

Here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  data:

services:

  blog:
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: blog
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=...1.rds.amazonaws.com
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=verysecret
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: data
        target: /var/www/html
      - type: bind
        source: ./uploads.ini
        target: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
```

Here is my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add a symlink in /var/www/html (in the container) like this.

```
ln -sf . blog
```